# Give Lightning Web Component a Prettier Name

Tags: lightning-web-components

How do I give my lightning web component a better name than simply 'helloWorld' or 'createNewCase' in the Custom section of the **Lightning App Builder** when published?  I want something like 'Hello World' and 'Create New Case' (Non-camel case capitalization with spaces).

**Note:** I tried changing the LightningComponentBundle tag fqn value, but that did not change the name in the UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `masterLabel` tag in the configuration XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="firstComponent">
  <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
    <masterLabel>First Component</masterLabel>
  <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage,lightning__AppPage,lightning__HomePage">
      <property name="label" type="String" default="WIPDeveloper.com"></property>
    </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Results in the following in setup.

[image]

Ref: https://fun-inspiration-5789-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags

Answer (score 4):

Use the **master label** tag in meta XML like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="parentCmp">
 <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
 <isExposed>true</isExposed>
 <masterLabel> Test Component </masterLabel>
 <targets>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
 </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```